# How can I pass arguments to a google maps object after init?

Tags: javascript, google-maps

I'm working with a Wordpress theme, and in it's page builder is a handy Google Maps element that works more-or-less the way I want it to. The only downside is it doesn't allow for styling (by a snazzy maps json for example).

Because of how the theme is written, I can't access the google maps initialization code directly. Is there a way I can create a function in my child theme with the styles, find the map object on the page and pass the styling function to it?

This is the rough blueprint of what I'm trying to achieve, didn't include the json file to simplify it.

```
var contact_map_styles = [
   // json styles will go here
   // ....
];

// Find the map on the page
if ($('#contact-map').length) {
    // Add styling function to the map
    // What would go here?
}
```

Thank you in advance for any help!

Comment: You need to access the `google.maps.Map` (javascript) object, not the div that contains it.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using  wordpress this mean that you have a php server side env.

If the value are already available at page loading you can set directly in you javascript code .. adding the value you need using echo  eg:

```
 if ($('#contact-map').length) {
 <?php 
    echo " var mlwStyles =[
                {
                    featureType: "poi",
                    elementType: "labels",
                    stylers: [
                          { visibility: "off" }
                    ]
                }
            ];";

 ?>

}
```

if you need  the value runtime you can use ajax eg:

```
 $.post('your_link', { your_param1: 'your_value1',  }, 
                    function (data) { your_function_for_manange_result(data); })
```

mean